# Correct query for nested like properties in ES (but w/o nested type)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Given this document in ES 1.7

```
 {
                  "_index": "prod",
                  "_type": "customerpropertieses",
                  "_id": "215c4bd7-7611-4c6a-8681-ef3b318613a0",
                  "_source": {
                    "properties": [
                      {
                        "extentionPropertyId": 7,
                        "propertyName": "Video Introduction",
                        "value": "bla"
                      },
                      {
                        "extentionPropertyId": 8,
                        "propertyName": "Guide Exp"
                      },
                    ],
                    "id": "215c4bd7-7611-4c6a-8681-ef3b318613a0",
                    "parentId": "2222"
                  } }
```

I would like to find a query that says if propertyName and value IN THE SAME curly braces match some values then return that customerpropertieses document.

Now I'm probably doing it wrong with the following query bc it returns a customerpropertieses document when ANY propertyName matches the query and ANY value matches the query. Basically I'd like to enforce groupings of propertyName and value to be from the same "object index"

ES Query that is not working correctly

```
"query":{
            "type": "customerpropertieses",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "propertyName": {
                                  "query": "Guide Exp"
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "value": {
                                  "query": "bla"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }       }
```

Do I need nested types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you indeed need to use nested document.
Slightly longer: Internally, ES "flatten" those so it looks like that in the Lucene index:

```
{
   extentionPropertyId: [7, 8],
   propertyName: ["Video Introduction", "Guide Exp"],
   value: ["bla"]
}
```

As you can see, the link between each "object" is lost.

Here's a longer explanation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html